# RUBY - Couldn't find User with 'id'=1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently receiving this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MainController#index

After I destroyed a preference, which was held by myself.

> Error:
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MainController#index
>
> Couldn't find User with 'id'=1

```
def get_owner
    return User.find( self.owner );  // LINE WITH ERROR
end
```

Here is `post.rb`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :ps_normal, :ps_locked, :ps_blocked, :ps_protected ]
  enum sortable: [ :school, :company, :date ]

  validates :owner, presence: true

  def owner_name
    return self.get_owner.display_name;
  end

  def get_owner
    return User.find( self.owner );
  end

  def readable?
    return (self.status != :blocked ) ? true : false;
  end
end
```

UPDATE#1

```
2.3.0 :001 > User.find(1)
User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:324:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:444:in `find_one'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:423:in `find_with_ids'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:131:in `find'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How should I fix this? Add userid=1?

Update #2

I deleted my own preference under my own username and I received this error. People are saying I am missing id=1, but I am unsure on how to add it back into the database

Comment: Can you open a Rails console (in the same environment) and check what `User.find(1)`'s output? As per the error most probably user with the `id=1` is not present in your database.

Comment: what do you mean by: `destroyed a preference, which was held by myself`?

Comment: @Michael, If you feel my answer helped [solved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please mark it as ‘[accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)' by clicking the green check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per your console output, there is no user with the id of `1`. So if you need a user with `id=1` you can do it like this.

First, create a user with the same details which you had for the deleted user. After the user successfully created then go to Rails console and:

```
u = User.last
# => #<User id: x, ...... >
u.update_column(:id, 1)
```

Please refer to [Rails API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) here for more info. Choose according to the Rails version that you are using.